# C++ Parent class Sub class , working with vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, subclass

C++

Hi, so basically I made an **Animal Parent class**
and have **Mouse as one of my SubClass**.

The **Mouse** has a unique function (not in the parent class) **get_scare** :

```
void get_scare()
```

In main, I created a vector of Animal Object:

```
vector<Animal> list_animal
```

My problem is after Identifying that the subclass mouse is **at index i** in **list_animal**, I cannot access my get_scare function. I can only access function in Animal (Parent Class).

How can I access specific functions in mouse, but also keep my vector of Animal.

This is what I did:

```
if (list_animals[i]->get_animal_name() == "Mouse") {
         
                list_animals[i] -> get_scare(); //Doesn't let me do that

            }
```

I understand that it does not let me do that since the Object is Animal, How do I go around that!

Thank you!

Comment: The best approach is to add `get_scare` as a `virtual` function to `Animal` so that the holder of the `Animal` doesn't need to know what kind of `Animal` they have. If this is unpalatable, use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to test if you have a `Mouse`, and then call  `get_scare` on the converted pointer. Going to be a few duplicates to this question, so look around the site a bit to see if you can find one before I can.

Comment: Additionally, it is impossible to store a `Mouse` instance in `vector<Animal>`, because that vector only holds precisely one type.  To store arbitrary Animal instances in that vector, you need at a minimum `vector<Animal*>`.  Preferably instead of raw pointers, you would use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.  If you might introduce other "scareable" animals, you might even choose to use multiple inheritance with a "Scareable" interface and use that with `dynamic_cast` when processing "scares".  Or you could consider moving it to the base class and introduce a "scare factor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot declare `vector<Animal>` and store a subclass object in it - this is a bug. For example, if you have

```
vector<Animal> list_animal(1);
list_animal[0] = Mouse{};
```

then any data members of `Mouse` that are not in `Animal` are thrown away - this is called *slicing*.

But maybe that was just a typo in your question since elsewhere you used `list_animals[i]->`. Let's assume you declared `vector<Animal*>` instead. In this case, you can do what you want by using a *cast*:

```
if (list_animals[i]->get_animal_name() == "Mouse") {
    static_cast<Mouse*>(list_animals[i])->get_scare();
    }
```

This, however, is not a good object-oriented design. A slightly better way, assuming `Animal` has a virtual destructor (which it should have), is to use `dynamic_cast` instead of relying on `get_animal_name()`:

```
if (auto mouse = dynamic_cast<Mouse*>(list_animals[i])) {
    mouse->get_scare();
    }
```

This is still not a typical object-oriented design. Normally, you either add `get_scare()` into `Animal`, or only use the function when `Mouse` rather than `Animal` is available.

Finally, you have to pay attention to who owns Animal-derived objects. Often you want the vector to own them, in which case you want a vector of *smart pointers*: `vector<unique_ptr<Animal>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<Animal>>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer !! yes it is an odd way to do it, but I had guidline to follow!!!